# Return a value based on a vlookup returning partial text

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to use a vlookup function nested inside a if function. What I am trying to do is autocomplete a form based on a Work Order number. I want to complete the section of the form that indicates if the order has been confirmed. I want to use vlookup to look through the categories for this specific order and find a text and return it (column I) then if the text contains "CNF" I want to return either "yes" or "no".

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tso3z.png)

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5r5d.png)

Comment: Sorry the description on the images are reversed.

Comment: How do you ' look through the categories for this specific order and find a text'? Which column contains the order categories?